# Using iOS Game Center, with Ejecta.js

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, game-center

I am seeing the following in my console, when I try to use the Ejecta .authenticate([callback]) method.

[MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

[MC] Reading from public effective user settings.

Anybody know why that is? I believe my provisioning and app id etc to be correct.

I have also read other threads relating to this message log regarding use of other phone peripherals such as the camera. It said these could be fixed by setting a value on privacy in info.plist, but I can not see a key in the list that makes any sense for Game Center.